How can I strictly rotate the background itself, without changing the HTML structure or using JavaScript?
As the question states, is this possible? To have an .element that holds information/data and also has a background that needs to be rotated—not the information (.element) itself, but the background image. This would be relatively trivial if the HTML syntax were modified to apply a mask for the image or text, or if a formula/function were created to apply a animation via JavaScript. But is it possible to achieve this within the same element without using JavaScript or changing the syntax for the HTML?
@keyframes rotateBackground {
    /* 
        An animation that strictly rotates the background, as opposed to the entire element.
    */

}

.element {
    background: url("some-image.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

    animation: rotateBackground 5s linear infinite;

    /*
        Other element styles unrelated to the background.
    */
}


How can I strictly rotate the background itself, without changing
the HTML structure or using JavaScript?


This might give you some ideas: how-to-rotate-the-background-image-in-the-container

duplicates do not seem to set a rotating animation, here is a possible trick https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KKOGLwM
